# Is there an efficient way to search in a sub-list of a list in java?

Tags: java

I have 2 Lists:

`L1=[2,4,7,9,14,15,17]` and `L2=[2,3,6]`

The second list contains the indexes of the elements I want to extract of the first.

```
for(int i=0;i<L1.size();i++){
    if(L2.contains(i)){
        //Do sth
    }
}
```

I would like to obtain a sub-list `L=[7,9,17]` without having to Browse the whole list `L1`.

Thank you.

Comment: make sure the first list is of type `ArrayList`, otherwise accessing elements of the `LinkedList` through indices would be the same as searching for element through iteration.

Answer (score 4):

Loop over L2, since it contains all the indices of L1 you are interested in:

```
for(int i : L2) {
    if(i < L1.length) {
        //Do sth with L1.get(i)
    }
}
```

And if you are sure the values of L2 are valid indices in L1, you don't need the condition:

```
for(int i : L2) {
    // Do sth with L1.get(i)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could wrap the two into a `List` of your own:

```
class ListComb<T> extends AbstractList<T> implements List<T> {
    private final List<T> l;
    private final List<Integer> comb;

    public ListComb(List l, List<Integer> comb) {
        this.l = l;
        this.comb = comb;
    }

    @Override
    public T get(int index) {
        return l.get(comb.get(index));
    }

    @Override
    public int size() {
        return comb.size();
    }
}

public void test(String[] args) {
    ListComb<Integer> l = new ListComb<>(Arrays.asList(2,4,7,9,14,15,17), Arrays.asList(2,3,6));
    System.out.println(l);
}
```